# Allow paswordless user to change to another passwordless user

Tags: security, users, sudo, non-root-user, su

I have two users `dev` and `tomcat` neither of them have a password.

How can I allow `dev` <sup>1</sup> do `su - tomcat` without having him having to enter any credentials?

<sup>1</sup> connects with ssh keyfile

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I ended up doing it.

I created the file `/etc/sudoers.d/dev`

Containing:

```
# allow user dev to become user tomcat
# invoked with [dev@host ~]$ sudo su - tomcat
dev ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/su - tomcat
```

changed the file permissions with `chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/dev`

created an alias in dev's `.bashrc` `alias tomcat='sudo su - tomcat'`

This results in the ability for the dev user to become the tomcat user without either having to type (or indeed having) a password ever by typing `tomcat` at the command line.

Answer (score 11):

If what you want is to allow `dev` to run arbitrary commands as `tomcat`, then don't bother with `su`, stick with sudo. Add the following line to the `sudoers` file (use the `visudo` command):

```
dev ALL = (tomcat) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Run `sudo -iu tomcat` as the user `dev` to run a login shell as `tomcat`.

Answer (score 7):

You have sudo added to your tags. In your sudoers file, you can add dev to allowed users and, if you wish, restrict which commands they're allowed to run, and that password isn't required. Then all they'd have to do is type "sudo su - tomcat".

Run `visudo` to add the following line:

```
dev ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/su - tomcat
```

There's lots more information and examples in the man file for sudoers.

Comment: still asks for the dev password

Comment: @Nifle There was an error in the sudoers line, try now.

Comment: @Gilles - still asks for a password. And had to add ALL=(ALL) to get it to run at all

Comment: @Nifle Oh, oops, still not right, I forgot the host column. Er, you realize that while `sudo` won't ask for credentials if you specify `NOPASSWD`, `su` is likely to ask for one?

Answer (score 2):

I've been using sudo's built in user assumption tool,

where

- `dev` is the sudoer user name, or
- `dev` is the sudeoer group name (sudo configuration calls this `%dev`)
- and `tomcat` is the destination user

> /!\ Note, always validate sudo's configuration files with `visudo` before writing, or always edit sudo's configuration files with `visudo`. An invalid sudo configuration file will latch sudo in an broken state and prevent further invocations.
>
> `sudo env EDITOR=nano visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/runas-tomcat`

```
#/etc/sudoers.d/runas-tomcat
dev ALL=(tomcat) NOPASSWD: ALL
%dev ALL=(tomcat) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Using sudo like this is simmilar to as follows. The flag `--set-home` (`-H`) is optional, it corrects `$HOME` by looking it up the target user home in `/etc/passwd`. The flag `--shell` (`-s`) or `--login` (`-i`) is optional, `-s` uses *your* shell and should feel at home, `-i` instead uses the target user shell specified in `/etc/passwd` which may be `/usr/sbin/nologin` for example and deny login; if both `-s` and `-i` are not provided, sudo requires additional non-flag arguments to speciify what command to run.

```
dev@localhost ~ $ sudo --set-home --shell --user tomcat
tomcat@localhost /home/dev/ $ cd
tomcat@localhost ~ $
```

or in shorter form

```
sudo -u tomcat  echo whoami
sudo -Hsu tomcat  # enter tomcat with your shell and their home
```